# Problem in configuring the APIM cluster with WSO2 APIM 3.2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

#### Description:

I build the APIM from [this](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/9d4c019c786b3f29bf12269a0bb9788df99d0904) commit and deploy the product on the VMs.
I configured APIM using Documents [1](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/) and [2](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/)
Then start the `traffic-manager`, `key-manager`, and `publisher` without any error.
But when I tried to log in to `example.com/publisher`, I experienced some errors.
Like below:
[logs.txt](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/files/7533627/logs.txt)
After getting these errors, I checked the service providers section and saw that the `apim_publisher` application was created but OAuth keys didn't exist.
Then I checked the consumer_key and consumer_secret's value on the `AM_SYSTEM_APPS` table in `apim_db` database, and both of them was undefined

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Build product-apim from [this commit](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/9d4c019c786b3f29bf12269a0bb9788df99d0904)
2. Move wso2am-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT to 5 VMs.
3. Run the below command for profile optimization for each node.
   `sh bin/profileSetup.sh  -Dprofile=$PROFILE_NAME`
4. Run components in the following order:

```
sh wso2am-3.2.0-tm/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=traffic-manager
sh wso2am-3.2.0-km/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager
sh wso2am-3.2.0-pub/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-publisher
```

5. Open the publisher page

#### Affected Product Version:

APIM 3.2.0 (MariaDB)

#### Environment details (with versions):

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Client: Ubuntu 20.04